# Max position of aggregated dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I want to get the maximum positions in a split by factor data frame, so that I can take the values of these positions in an additional dataframe.
As example. Let's say I have this DF:

```
df1=data.frame(groups=c('a','a','b','b','b','c'), c1=c(1:6), c2=c(2:7), c3=c(4:9))

print(df1)

row.    groups  c1  c2  c3

1.  a   1   2   4
2.  a   2   3   5
3.  b   3   4   6
4.  b   4   5   7
5.  b   5   6   8
6.  c   6   7   9


aggregate(df1[,2:4], by=list(df1$groups), FUN=max)



Group.1 c1 c2 c3

 1.       a  2  3  5      
 2.       b  5  6  8
 3.       c  6  7  9
```

As I've found finding the max value of every column by group is easy.
But now I want the position of the aggregated max to use in an additional dataframe so that if:

```
df2=cbind(df1$groups,0-df1[,2:4])

print(df2)



df1$groups c1 c2 c3

1.          a -1 -2 -4        
2.          a -2 -3 -5
3.          b -3 -4 -6
4.          b -4 -5 -7
5.          b -5 -6 -8
6.          c -6 -7 -9
```

I want the value in df2 that is max in df1. e.g:

```
Group.1 c1 c2 c3

1.       a  -2  -3  -5     
2.       b  -5  -6  -8
3.       c  -6  -7  -9
```

(This is a malipulation done only for the example. My original data is more complicated but this is what I need)

Meanwhile I've done a double loop but this is really not efficient enough.

I am using:

> ```
> R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
> Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> ```

Comment: You can do convert rownames to a column before the aggregation and then merge on that

Comment: Please stick to a single programming language in your questions; otherwise it becomes too broad.

Comment: For a vector (column) you can use the `which.max()` function. Not sure how to do it for multiple columns simultaneously.

Comment: Although `which()` has some options that may work for you. For instance, to find the position of the max value in your dataframe you can use: `which(df1[,2:4] == max(df1[,2:4]), arr.ind = TRUE)`

Comment: @Sotos but if the index is now a number the max function will take the max index of this col instead of the index where each col has the max

Comment: No, the max is applied only on variables c1 - c3

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to convert the rownames to a column, and create an index vector with them. Then use that vector to filter `df2`, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

ind <-df1 %>% 
        rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
        group_by(groups) %>% 
        filter_at(names(.)[3:5], all_vars(. == max(.))) %>% 
        pull(rn)

#[1] "2" "5" "6"

df2[i1,]
```

which gives

> ```
>   df1$groups c1 c2 c3
> 2          a -2 -3 -5
> 5          b -5 -6 -8
> 6          c -6 -7 -9
> ```

Comment: as the example data frame has increasing values per column, this will work, but I think it won't work if the data is random (i.e. if for instance for group 1, col1 has the max at row 1 and col2 at row 2)

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum I know, I saw that but I am following the logic of the question where it is inferred that ALL values of the row will be the max values of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be not particularly trivial if the row index of the max value can differ from column to column (as I mentioned in the comment to the answer above). I think you cannot avoid double iteration then (once over the group a/b/c and once over the column) to get the max value for each column. You can do so for instance via:

```
library(dplyr)
idx_df <- df1 %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarise_all(which.max) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% select(-groups)
df2_split <- df2[,-1] %>% split(df2$"df1$groups")

sapply(seq_along(df2_split), function(df_idx) 
  sapply(seq_along(df2_split[[df_idx]]), function(col_idx)
    df2_split[[df_idx]][idx_df[df_idx,col_idx], col_idx])
  ) %>% t %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  `rownames<-`(names(df2_split)) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(colnames(idx_df))
```

So this first makes an idx_df that stores the indices of the max values for each of the groups (you could also use `aggregate` for that) and then retrieves the max values out of df2 by first splitting df2.

Does that increase the speed? An all-dplyr-solution would be more elegant, but I am not sure if that is possible.